# I want to know what is font-family in Ubuntu!

Tags: ubuntu-font-family

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, and I really like this font-family.

Soon, I will replace my laptop. And I want to take this font to my new laptop.

Can I know what is font-family that used in Ubuntu 18.04?

I think it is sans-selif font, but I couldn't find the name.

Comment: https://design.ubuntu.com/font/

Comment: https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=what%27s+ubuntu%27s+font-family

Answer (score 2):

The default font in Ubuntu is called "Ubuntu" (surprise ;-) ).

You can find more details about it here: https://design.ubuntu.com/font

The font is distributed under an open source license and you can download it from the above Ubuntu website, Google Web Fonts and a few other places.